# Keeping Vue slot reactivity when manually adding it to DOM via appendChild()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

- I have a Vue component that has a default slot.
- The contents of the slot needs to be added to different DOM element (element created by 3rd-party JS lib).
- `<slot></slot>` is not used in the template but the slot VNode is still accessible via this.$slots.default.

## Adding VNode to DOM

```
const slotContainer = document.createElement('div');
targetElement.appendChild(slotContainer);
const slot = this.$slots.default;
const v = new Vue({
  render: () => slot
}).$mount(slotContainer);
```

The above code renders the slot in the DOM but reactivity is not working.

## Getting reactivity working

I noticed if I add `<slot></slot>` to the component template then the slot becomes reactive. Although this works I would prefer to exclude the `<slot></slot>` in the template because then I have to use v-if to hide it. Vue obviously does something special to a slot when it is defined in the template that enables reactivity, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Indeed, if you add a DOM element inside a Vue element, it's not part of its Shadow DOM and thus won't consider it as part of its reactivity system. If it works when adding `<slot />`, then you have a working solution for a hacky feature :)

Comment: Do you know how Vue makes the slot part of the shadow DOM? Is it done through the Vue template compiler?

Comment: It's part of Vue core, its runtime not the compiler, that's how it mounts the whole application.